# how to get the size of td

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a table which in which i have td .when i click in text field which has onkeypress
event select values from database a table is shown from whic i select value.this select table is in div which position is fixed.but it will also chang the height

```
<td class="value">vehicle </td><td> 
 <input type="text" id="txt_sh_vid" onKeyPress="vhc_record()" maxlength="4">
  <div id="div_vhc"  class="search_form">
</div>


 <input type="text" id="vid" style="display:none;">
```

JavaScript:

```
function vhc_record() {
    var data = 'vhc=' + document.getElementById('txt_sh_vid').value;
    loadXMLDoc('ship/vehicle_ship/', 'div_vhc', data);
    document.getElementById('div_vhc').style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

it is css of the above table

```
    td.value
    {
    background-color:#00628B;
    color:#E6E6DC;
    height:50;

    }

    div.search_form
    {
    position:fixed;
     background-color:white;

}
```

when i press key in textfield it will also change the height of **class="value"** 
like **div id="div_vhc"** while its height is 50

Comment: What is your actual problem / question?

Comment: @sadi is this your entire code? where is the javascript part?

Comment: @kjy its javascript code
'function vhc_record()
{
var  data='vhc='+document.getElementById('txt_sh_vid').value;
 loadXMLDoc('ship/vehicle_ship/','div_vhc',data);
  document.getElementById('div_vhc').style.visibility="visible";
}'

Comment: @Sadi so you basically want to change the size of height of the td when someone onkeypress on the textfield right?

Comment: @kjy no idont want it.iwant it that the size of the td is remained same its height:50;

Comment: @sadi so what is the questions? you want `td.value` height to always be 50px?

Comment: @kjy plz give me answer
i want the td.value 50px

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/nM28U/).  Let me know if this is what you are looking for:

I am guessing what you are looking for is to grab `td.value` width and height.  You can use `offsetHeight` or `offsetWidth`

I am not very sure what you are trying to do, but to get the height of `td.value` you can do the following assume based on the structure of html.  of course if you wish to traverse through all td element and find the element w/ the class name value then you'll have to use regex to match the element with value as part of its class:

Your vhc_record function midified:

```
var myvalue = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0];  //grabs the td.value element based on your html markup

document.getElementById('div_vhc').style.height = myvalue.offsetHeight+'px';  //sets div_vhc height to that of td.value
document.getElementById('div_vhc').style.width= myvalue.offsetWidth+'px';//sets div_vhc width to that of td.value
```

The changes i made to the html and css and i added some visiblity properties to make the example looks apparent:

```
<table><tr><td class="value">vehicle </td></tr></table>
<input type="text" id="txt_sh_vid" onKeyPress="vhc_record()" maxlength="4">
<div id="div_vhc"  class="search_form">
</div>


<input type="text" id="vid" style="display:none;">

td.value
{
    background-color:#00628B;
    color:#E6E6DC;
    height: 50px;   
    width: 50px;
}

#div_vhc
{
    position:fixed;
    background-color:white;
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Add **table-layout:fixed** to the **TABLE** element style.

Step 2: Add **overflow: hidden** to the **TD** element style.

Here is an example where the inner DIV is taller than the containing TD, but the TD will stay at 50 and hide the rest:

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed">
    <tr>
        <td style="overflow:hidden;height:50px;border:solid 1px #000">
            <div style="height:100px;background:#f00">Hello<br>I am a very<br>very<br>very<br>very<br>long<br>multiline<br>text...</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

if you want to have it scroll instead, use overflow:scroll in the td element style.