# how to use div tag like table

Tags: html, css

how to set the position of **div tag** like **table** in proper order.

```
<html>
<head><title> .</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="style/main.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/ajax.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script/validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/date-picker.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div onclick="show_tb()"style="width:70%;float:left;" class="title_mrwat" >

NEW MARWAT OIL TRANSPORTER
</div>
<div style="width:30%;float:right;">
<address>
Address:P/O Box 564, Landekotal Peshawar<br />
Phone: +12 34 56 78
</address>

</div>

<div style="width:50%;float:left;">
<img src="images/pso.jpg" height="45" width="45" />
<img src="images/total.jpg" height="50" width="55" />
<img src="images/shell.jpg" height="50" width="45" />
<img src="images/caltex.jpg" height="35" width="35" />
<img src="images/attock.jpg" height="40" width="40" />

</div>


<div style="width:50%;float:right;"id="tb">
<input  type="button" value="product"onmouseover="className='menuon';" onmouseout="className='menuoff';" onclick="loadXMLDoc('product/','formTag' ,'')" value="product">
<input   type="button" value="owner" onclick="loadXMLDoc('owner/','formTag')" value="shipment" onmouseover="className='menuon';" onmouseout="className='menuoff';">
<input  type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc('vehicle/','formTag')" value="vehicle" onmouseover="className='menuon';" onmouseout="className='menuoff';">
<input   type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc('route/','formTag')" value="route" onmouseover="className='menuon';" onmouseout="className='menuoff';">
<input  type="button" value="shipment" onclick="loadXMLDoc('ship/','formTag')" value="shipment" onmouseover="className='menuon';" onmouseout="className='menuoff';">
<input type="button" id="bt" value="report" onclick="show_form()" style="background-color:#E6E6DC;" >
</div>

<div id="responseTag" class="show_rpt" style="width:100%;">

</div>

<div id="div_added" class="div_add">
</div>
<div id="formTag">


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unsurprisingly, I don't understand what you want after only 13 words of description. Could you write a longer question?

Comment: @thirty i wnt to **div** act like a table (tr(td,td) tr(td,td))

Comment: can you please clarify your question?  it's extremely hard to help you if we dont' understand what you wish to accomplish.  Also, this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362560/how-to-get-the-size-of-td

Comment: @thirty i want **<div>** divide the page like **table**
<table>
<tr>
<td>first column in first row</td>
<td>second  column in first row</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>first column in second row</td>
<td>second  column in second row</td>

</tr>

Answer (score 1):

Use the same float direction for all divs.

```
<div style="width:50%;float:left"> first </div>
<div style="width:50%;float:left"> second </div>
```

will create two divs floating. However you need to be careful with width: 50%, it may not work. And you need to break floating after each "row" with clear: left/right/both.

Comment: `<div style="width:50%;float:left"> first </div>
<div style="width:50%;float:left"> second </div>`
umean it work like first row or column?

Comment: First row. You should read some guides on html+css. Understanding things like float is a basic requirement to design web pages and described in countless guides.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the display type of the `<div>` with CSS

```
display:table;
```

By default a `<div>` is a block element which would be this in CSS

```
display:block;
```

You would probably need to put `<div>`'s for `<tr>`'s and `<td>`'s in there as well